# JavaScript - Trying to filter data

Tags: javascript, api, express

Whenever I use this function, it will not retrieve data without specifying a title.

The point of this is supposed to be to filter through looking for authorid, and then search.

But if no search "title" is provided, I still want to return all of the Cards.

Can you tell me what in my code I would need to correct in order for this to happen?:

```
//Finds All of the User's Cards, and allows Searching by Title
exports.findMyCards2 = (req, res) => {
  const { page, size, title, authorid } = req.query;
  const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);
  Card.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset,
    where: {
      authorid: { [Op.like]: `%${authorid}%` },
      title: { [Op.like]: `%${title}%` || ""}  // I tried to add || "" here
    } 
  })
    .then(data => {
      const response = getPagingData(data, page, limit);
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Cards."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Smells like a code request.

Comment: It works getting BOTH, but not one. I figured it's something really simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Did you read anything I've posted yet?

Comment: You need an `if` statement somewhere to check if `title` is empty or not. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I thought the " || "") at the end of the where-title would handle that part.

Comment: I see... So that is what you actually tried? Ok then.

Comment: The thing is if the `title` already is empty... Adding an *"or empty" doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQL `LIKE ""` is looking for empty values.

So you need to send a different `WHERE clause` to the DB if there is no `title` in the request.

```
//Finds All of the User's Cards, and allows Searching by Title
exports.findMyCards2 = (req, res) => {
  const { page, size, title, authorid } = req.query;
  const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);
  
  // Your default query
  let query = {
    authorid: { [Op.like]: `%${authorid}%` },
    title: { [Op.like]: `%${title}%`}
  }

  // Query if the title is undefined (Remove the a title criteria of the WHERE)
  if(!title){
    query = {
      authorid: { [Op.like]: `%${authorid}%` }
    }
  }
  
  Card.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset,
    where: query  // Then use it here
  })
    .then(data => {
      const response = getPagingData(data, page, limit);
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Cards."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: This looks right to me, but it still doesn't work if I have in only the author. I still get zero results back.

Comment: Could you console.log the `title` in that case of no title? is it an empty string or `undefined`? If so... Just change the condition ;)

Comment: Then `if(!title){` will do

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! I'm testing it and it all works like I was hoping. I really appreciate your help, my apologies for not being more clear in the intro. Thanks a bunch!